# Facebook online account (it's in development, ask administrator to have access)

Tags: facebook

In Ubuntu 20.04 there is the chance to add an Online Account.
See the screenshot below (sorry about Polish but it is the language set in my machine):

[image: Online Account]

Is this an alternative solution than a bookmark in Firefox to login to Facebook?
Which is the effect of adding a Facebook account there?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a facebook account into Gnome Online accounts, you will have the ability to view the photos associated with your facebook account in the Gnome Photos app.

Similarly, if you were to add a gmail account, Nautilus just adds my gdrive and gdocs as shortcuts within the file browser.

Comment: For Google account, it also allows you to add your Google calendar to the GNOME calendar app. Not sure about Facebook, as it's calendar is probably not accessible over CalDAV protocol.

Comment: i can't log in...